# Functional abstraction to find nth root of a number - Newton raphson

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, numerical-methods

Below is the solution:

```
def approx_deriv(fn, x, dx=0.00001):
    return (fn(x + dx) - fn(x))/dx

def improve(update, isdone, guess=1, max_iterations=100):
    def recur_improve(guess, i):
        if i > max_iterations or isdone(guess):
           return guess
        else:
           return recur_improve(update(guess), i + 1)
    return recur_improve(guess, 1)

def newtons_method(fn, guess =1, max_iterations=100):
    def newtons_update(guess):
        return guess - fn(guess) / approx_deriv(fn, guess)
    def newtons_isdone(guess):
        ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN = 0.0000001
        return abs(fn(guess)) <= ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN
    return improve(newtons_update, 
                        newtons_isdone, 
                        max_iterations)

def nth_root(rootfunc, x):
    return rootfunc(x)
```

Test output:

```
>python -i nth_root.py
>>> def cuberoot(x):
...     return newtons_method(lambda y: y * y * y - x)
...
>>> result = nth_root(cuberoot, 27)
>>> result
3.000000000000141
>>>
```

My question:

Above is the functional abstraction for finding the \$n_{th}\$ root of a number. Is it possible to improve this abstraction?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `i > max_iterations or isdone(guess)`?

Comment: yes, it is `or`, query edited

Answer (score 1):

First, congratulations for the work you did : one can easily see that you put some thinking into it and as far as I have tested it, it works.

However, I still have a few comments and most of them are about the fact that you might have tried to be too clever.

Indeed, the use of both recursion and nested functions is a bit too much for my brain. Among other things, it took me a while to spot that the `guess` argument of the `newtons_method` is not used (and I am not even sure of it, am I right ?). You could make is easier to grasp by using names conveing more meaning.

Here's my attempt to un-nest functions and to change names (I am fully aware that they are not perfect) :

```
def recur_improve(next_step, isdone, x, i, max_iterations):
    if i > max_iterations or isdone(x):
       return x
    else:
       return recur_improve(next_step, isdone, next_step(x), i + 1, max_iterations)

def improve(next_step, isdone, initval=1, max_iterations=100):
    return recur_improve(next_step, isdone, initval, 1, max_iterations)

def newtons_method(fn, max_iterations=100):
    def newtons_step(x):
        return x - fn(x) / approx_deriv(fn, x)
    def newtons_isdone(x):
        ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN = 0.0000001
        return abs(fn(x)) <= ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN
    return improve(newtons_step,
                        newtons_isdone,
                        max_iterations)
```

Then, the recursion can be easily replaced by a while loop :

```
def improve(next_step, isdone, initval=1, max_iterations=100):
    x = initval
    i = 1
    while i < max_iterations and not isdone(x):
        x = next_step(x)
        i +=1
    return x
```

Then, one can see that counting iterations is boring. We have builtins to do this in a concise and efficient way.

```
def improve(next_step, isdone, initval=1, max_iterations=100):
    x = initval
    i = 1
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        if isdone(x):
            break
        x = next_step(x)
    return x
```

(I might have introduced on off-by-one error in the iteration counts but I can't be bothered).

Then, instead of passing functions using your original functions, you could just write conditions directly :

```
def improve(fn, initval=1, max_iterations=100, epsilon=0.0000001):
    x = initval
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        if abs(fn(x)) <= epsilon:
            break
        x -= fn(x) / approx_deriv(fn, x)
    return x
```

Then you don't even need to have multiple functions anymore and your code boils down to :

```
def newtons_method(fn, initval, max_iterations=100, epsilon=0.00000001):
    x = initval
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        if abs(fn(x)) <= epsilon:
            break
        x -= fn(x) / approx_deriv(fn, x)
    return x
```

It seems much clearer to me.

Also, your `def nth_root(rootfunc, x)` function doesn't seem really useful to me. You could just have :

```
def cuberoot(x):
    return newtons_method(lambda y: y * y * y - x, x)

result = cuberoot(27**3)

print(result)
```

And get the result you expect.

Finally, your function deserves some documentation.

**Final code :**

```
def approx_deriv(fn, x, dx=0.00001):
    """ some docstring. """
    return (fn(x + dx) - fn(x))/dx


def newtons_method(fn, initval, max_iterations=100, epsilon=0.00000001):
    """ some docstring. """
    x = initval
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        if abs(fn(x)) <= epsilon:
            break
        x -= fn(x) / approx_deriv(fn, x)
    return x

def cuberoot(x):
    """ some docstring. """
    return newtons_method(lambda y: y * y * y - x, x)

result = cuberoot(27**3)

print(result)
```

Comment: yes, `guess` argument is not used.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the `and`/`or` issue I commented on, there's another bug in your code: when `newtons_method` calls `improve`, it passes `max_iterations` as the `guess` parameter. You should pass it by keyword or supply the `guess` argument (which you do provide, unused, as a default argument to `newtons_method`) positionally too.

This demonstrates the importance of proper testing; with only a single test case, an initial `guess` of `100` still gets to the correct answer within the default `100` steps. I added `print(guess)` to `improve` while testing and updating, which would have helped you spot the issue.

---

I think your derivative approximation will be slightly more accurate if you *bracket* `x`:

```
def approx_deriv(fn, x, dx=0.00001):
    """Approximate derivative of fn at x."""
    return (fn(x + dx) - fn(x - dx)) / (2 * dx)
```

I have also added a docstring - this is general good practice.

---

You could factor out the nested function in `improve`:

```
def improve(update, isdone, guess=1, max_iterations=100):
    """Improve the guess to a specified accuracy or iteration count."""
    if isdone(guess) or max_iterations == 0:
        return guess
    return improve(update, isdone, update(guess), max_iterations-1)
```

Note that you don't need an explicit `else` case where the `if` block will `return`.

---

`ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN` is constant, so I'd declare it at the top level of the script rather than bury it in a nested function. You can use that as the default value, to allow another value to be supplied where necessary (this currently isn't an easy option):

```
ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN = 0.0000001

...

def newtons_method(fn, guess=1, max_iterations=100,
                   margin=ALLOWED_ERROR_MARGIN):
    """Use Newton's method to approximate x for fn(x) == 0."""
    def newtons_update(guess):
        return guess - fn(guess) / approx_deriv(fn, guess)
    def newtons_isdone(guess):
        return abs(fn(guess)) <= margin
    return improve(newtons_update, newtons_isdone,
                   guess, max_iterations)
```

---

There is no point to the `nth_root` function. Surely:

```
cuberoot(27)
```

is more readable than:

```
nth_root(cuberoot, 27)
```

It's not even a particularly accurate name, as all it does is call the first argument (which doesn't have to be at all related to finding roots) with the second. I would also write `y ** 3` rather than `y * y * y`.

---

One thing to watch out for is `lambda`'s late binding behaviour (see e.g. [Local variables in Python nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614/3001761)). If you tried to solve multiple equations at the same time, you might get surprising behaviour. You can solve this with e.g.:

```
def cuberoot(x):
    """Approximate the cube root of x."""
    return newtons_method(lambda y, x=x: y ** 3 - x)
                                  # ^ note
```